# Stay on the game screen android

Tags: android

What code is not always turn off the clash of clans screen?

The charging time is connected and not connected.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: I don't even remotely understand what you are asking. I think this question needs a lot of work.

Comment: Try breaking your question into multiple parts... What do you want to happen? What is happening? What errors (if any) do you get? What have you tried already? // If you can add that into your question, it should be much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking what keeps the screen on?

You don't have to use WAKE_LOCK, it's sufficient to add "android:keepScreenOn="true".

As an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true" >
```